How can I cut up this complex object that isn't liking boolean operations?
For well over a full day, I've been trying to chop up a complex object I've sculpted with boolean operations and Blender is generally just not having it.
I've been through all kinds of things; Making sure it's manifold, all transforms applied, extruded surfaces into cut tools, solidified parts and surfaces, tried with basic shapes instead, checked normals, exported to Meshmixer and back to check and fix etc. The object shows a bunch of intersecting faces even though I've tried to merge by distance I'm still exactly where I was before. I'm not even sure if they're the cause of the problem or not.
I've uploaded the stripped down Blender file (352mb) and it features the object to cut and the objects I want to cut with.
I'm at the end of my tether and I really hope I can get some help and advice to save my sanity with this and similar future tasks. ​Even though the target object is janky, I imagine this must be possible somehow.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o8tLaPZN3CMiEXhOJJNjMrEv8j5RW1Ff/view?usp=drive_link


Well, I think that in the process of creating the file to upload, I've inadvertantly cleaned up some of the parts and I've finally chunked it.
What a terrible waste of a weekend, but at least it's done.
And thanks to anyone that tried to help.

Are you trying to use a boolean with a 2d plane? That's not really going to work even if the object is manifold. You can give the planes a Solifdify modifier, even if it's pretty thin, and that should make it work.
Another way to divide the object is to go into sculpt mode and use the mask tool to paint the area you want to separate. Then go to Mask->Mask Slice as new Object

I've not been using 2d shapes. I've just reduced the cuts from 3d shapes I had down to the basic surface for the purpose of the file I'm sharing for the sake of clarity. As mentioned, I've been trying to cut with objects created from extrusions and solidifications from these surfaces.

Your link requires authorization.

Sorry. I've sorted the permissions and I've re-uploaded so that it has 3d shapes instead of surfaces.
